# Check row for a specific string and get the value of a column cell where the initial parameter was located

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a calendar checker that checks if a value is detected on a specific date and return the month it was detected at:

[image]

In the image I am looking for the string "FN" anywhere in the row. (or check table below)

| checker | M | T | W | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Jan-02 | Jan-03 | Jan-04 | Jan-05 |
| detected |  | **FN |  |  |

I want to use have the detected be the Month where "FN" was detected.
here is my current formula to check the row.
So the result should be "Jan" / "January"

```
=IF((NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&"FN"&"*",J3:3,0)))),"FN Found","FN Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MATCH` function will return the index of the first find. So in your example, it would be **2**.

You can then use that with the `INDEX` function to get the value of the date in row 2.

Then turn the date into a month using either cell format, or the `MONTH` function will return between 1 and 12:

`=MONTH(INDEX(B$2:H$2,0,MATCH("FN",B3:H3)))`

[image]

If you just use the cell format to display the date as a month, then it will look fine, but the cells will have different values, which might annoy you if you want to count them.

You can also add your error detection to get 'not found' instead of 'N/A' if there is not match